# Extract number after expression multiple times

Tags: r, regex, multiple-columns

I'd like to extract the number immediately following the expression "BINDING " and put that into a new column for every time I see that expression.

Ex:
Turn this column

```
Binding site
BINDING 346 346 jakdjf;aj [0984]. BINDING 28 28 jdalkjda.
BINDING 12 12 jklbasdjf;la.
```

To this

```
Bindsite1   Bindsite2                                              
346         28
12          NA
```

I can extract the first number with

```
fulldata <- fulldata %>% 
   extract(`Binding site`, into=c("bind"),
      regex = "(?<=BINDING\\s)([0-9]+)", 
      remove = FALSE)
```

but I'm not sure if you can do multiple extractions with this function. Note: I don't know how many columns I need but I think its around 5.

Comment: Could you please show the dput of the example.  It is not clear where the column starts and ends

Comment: Sorry, what is a dput? The column in my example is two rows long if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are starting off with a character vector of length 2, a base R alternative is

```
# extract a list of numeric vectors, one per element in the character vector
myList <- lapply(regmatches(temp, gregexpr("BINDING \\d+", temp)),
                 function(x) as.numeric(sub("BINDING ", "", x, fixed=TRUE)))
# get max length of numeric vectors
maxL <- max(lengths(myList))

# construct data.frame and add names with setNames
setNames(data.frame(t(sapply(myList, function(x) x[seq_len(maxL)]))),
         paste0("binding", seq_len(maxL)))
```

This returns a data.frame with two columns.

```
  binding1 binding2
1      346       28
2       12       NA
```

**data**

```
temp <- 
c("BINDING 346 346 jakdjf;aj [0984]. BINDING 28 28 jdalkjda", 
"BINDING 12 12 jklbasdjf;la")
```

Answer (score 2):

**1) strapplyc/read.pattern** Assuming `DF`, as in the Note at the end, define the pattern, `pat`, which is a reasonably simple regular expression consisting of matching BINDING, a space and a capture group of digits.  Now compute the column names, `cn`, by using `strapplyc` to extract the matches to `pat` on each line, count them using `lengths` and then find the maximum of those lengths giving the number of columns.  Use that to construct the column names, `cn`.  In the next line read in the data using `read.pattern` and the same pattern `pat` making use of column names just computed.

```
library(gsubfn)

pat <- "BINDING (\\d+)"
cn <- paste0("Bindsite", seq_len(max(lengths(strapplyc(DF[[1]], pat)))))
read.pattern(text = DF[[1]], pattern = pat, fill = TRUE, col.names = cn)
```

giving:

```
  Bindsite1 Bindsite2
1       346        28
2        12        NA
```

**2) strapply** A variation of the above is one line longer but the individual lines are relatively simple and it only does the matching once (rather than twice).  It uses `strapply` with the same regular expression as (1) to get a list each of whose elements is a vector of the matched numbers on one line.  It then calculates the maximum length of each such vector and expands each such element of `s` to that length.  Finally, it rbind's them all together and sets the column names.  The result is the numeric matrix `m`:

```
library(gsubfn)

s <- strapply(DF[[1]], "BINDING (\\d+)", as.numeric)
mx <- max(lengths(s))
m <- do.call("rbind", lapply(s, "length<-", mx))
colnames(m) <- paste0("Bindsite", 1:ncol(m))
```

giving:

```
> m
     Bindsite1 Bindsite2
[1,]       346        28
[2,]        12        NA
```

**Note:** The input `DF` in reproducible form is assumed to be:

```
Lines <- "Binding site
BINDING 346 346 jakdjf;aj [0984]. BINDING 28 28 jdalkjda.
BINDING 12 12 jklbasdjf;la."
DF <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE, sep = "\1", as.is = TRUE)
```

Comment: HI, I'm using your first example and I've figured out that it breaks down when I try it on my data, I'm noticing that if you make the second row have more "BINDING 97" regions to split than the previous row, it fails

Answer (score 0):

**1)** It is not clear about the structure of the dataset.  So we read it with `readLines`, extract the numbers after 'BINDING' using `str_extract_all` and `rbind` the `list` elements after padding `NA` for elements have length less than the maximum length.

```
library(stringr)
lst <- lapply(str_extract_all(lines[-1], "(?<=BINDING\\s)\\d+\\s*"), as.numeric)
m1 <- do.call(rbind, lapply(lst, `length<-`, max(lengths(lst))))
colnames(m1) <- paste0(sub("\\s+", "", lines[1]), seq_len(ncol(m1)))
m1 
#      Bindingsite1 Bindingsite2
#[1,]          346           28
#[2,]           12           NA
```

Note: No external packages used except `stringr`

#### data

```
lines <- readLines("file.txt")
```